# Toggle display of some element after some time

Tags: javascript, css, dom

How I can toggle the display os some element? I wanna be able to change the display of #clipboard-text for x seconds and return to "none" after that time.

CSS:

```
#clipboard-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #05B1DB;
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
clipboardButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let text = document.getElementById('display-text').innerHTML
  if (!text) return
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  document.getElementById('clipboard-text').style.display = "block"
})
```

And one more thing, I tried to use animation on that element but isn't working, why?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: what animation? that isn't in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simpler to add/remove classes instead of styles. You were basically just missing the [setTimeout() function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) which removes again the style.

```js
let clipboardElement = document.getElementById('clipboard-text');
let clipboardButton = document.querySelector('.the-button');
clipboardButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let text = document.getElementById('display-text').innerHTML
  if (!text) return
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  clipboardElement.classList.add('hey')
  var timeoutID = window.setTimeout( () => {
      clipboardElement.classList.remove('hey')
      window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }, 2000) // runs the function after 2000ms = 2 seconds
})
```

```css
#clipboard-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #05B1DB;
  display: none;
}

#clipboard-text.hey {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="clipboard-text">clipboard text we call it</div>
<button class="the-button">click me</button>

<div id="display-text">yes this element is also needed, why so ever he/she dind't mention it in the question</div>
```

Comment: I did something a little different but this will definitely work.